# QGIS polygon areas inside a polygon

Tags: qgis, vector

I'm having hard time doing the following analysis in QGIS:

I have watershed polygons with individual IDs.

Then I have four different shape files, each having different land use polygons.

I would like to know the areas of each land use inside a individual watershed polygon.